# How to reload paticular section of html using ajax and pjax?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax, laravel

I am new in pjax. I am just trying to reload certain portion of html after post some data when click on table span anchor(a) html tags.
But it's not working.
My html code  is:

```
<div id="container">
      @if($task->member_responsible == $task->created_by)
          <td><span class="auto-complete">Auto-Completed</span></td>
             @elseif($task->status == true)
          <td class="taskStatus">
          <span class="completed status" id="{{$task->id}}" status="false"><a href="{{route('task.list')}}" data-pjax="#container"> Completed</a></span></td>
         @elseif($task->status == false)
           <td class="taskStatusFalse"><span class="incomplete status" id="{{$task->id}}" status="true"><a href="{{route('task.list')}}" data-pjax="#container">Incomplete</a></span></td>
         @else
           <td></td>
     @endif
</div>
```

My Pjax and ajax code is:-

```
  $(document).ready(function () {
        $(".status").click(function () {
            var status = $(this).attr('status');
            var id = $(this).attr('id');
            $.ajax({
                type: "GET",
                url: "{{route('task.status.update')}}",
                data: {status: status, id: id, "_token": "{{ csrf_token() }}"},
                success: function () {
                    $(document).pjax('[data-pjax] a, a[data-pjax]', '#pjax-container')
                }
            });
        })
    });
```

My exact needs was I m just try to update data from ajax and change the status of task in database has been reloaded without page refresh and open or redirect what I mention in **data-pjax="#container"** anchor section and reload only container div section only. I am feel greatful and thankful if anyone can help me to solve out this problem. My code just be done reload the full page. But I just want to reload container div section only.

Comment: You want whole page refresh or some content ? please describe.

Comment: Some html content section.

Comment: You have to create copy of html content section which will change on click in a separate blade file. After that, on link click you will make a ajax call to a controller function where you will render small view and then return response to ajax call. Now, On success you have to replace current section content with response.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should look into rending a partial view on the server side to fill the div and then updating that with the json response. Much like a typical request that goes through the controller route and method, you can load a blade template, render it and then store it as data in your json response. Then its just a matter of injecting it into the container you specified. Keep in mind, nothing will be bound to the partial so if you require so, it will need to be done after you inject it into the container.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I am trying but it's also be load full page.

Comment: You said you wanted to fill the data-pjax container only, now you want a full page also?

Comment: Yes. But data-pjax section has been changed in each click.